# Android set content type HttpPost

Tags: android, encoding, header, http-post, content-type

How can you change the content-type of a HttpPost in android?

For a request I need to set the content type to application/x-www-form-urlencoded

So i got this bit of code:

```
httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
httppost= new HttpPost(url);
StringEntity se = new StringEntity(""); 
se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
httppost.setEntity(se);
```

But that doesn't do the trick and I cant find the solution anywhere.

Cheers

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(builder.getUrl());
            httppost.setHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,
                    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
            // Add your data
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(builder
                    .getNameValuePairs(), "UTF-8"));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

Note: the builder just contains url and namevalue pairs.

Comment: I'm already setting another header, due to the fact the form is also an authentication request. Wouldn't this override that ?

Comment: Got it all working, thanks! (The header does not get overwritten).

Comment: You can use `HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE` instead of `"Content-Type"`

Comment: can you please include the lines of code that build `builder` ?

Comment: @msysmilu Its just an URL and a list of name value pairs. It has nothing to do with the question. Please see http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/entity/UrlEncodedFormEntity.html

Comment: Yeah man @wtsang02, thanks for editing your answer with my editing suggestions! Really nice of you. NOT
There are people using their time to improve things on this page; why wouldn't you give them the credit?

Comment: Also, if you argue that what I asked has nothing to do with the question then I'll have you know that the question can be answered without your last 3 lines of code.

Comment: Still some fields getting null for me by setting httppost.setHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"); not working for me

Answer (score 8):

**Deprecated: `nameValuePairs`**

**Alternative: use `volley library`**

The complete code for the call, for whoever might need it.

```
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", "password"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "user1"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "password1"));

    HttpClient httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("www.yourUrl.com");
    httppost.setHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");

    try {
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "UTF-8"));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    try {
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        Log.d("Response:" , response.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: nameValuePairs is deprecated . Can you edit your snippet with Map or HashMap ?

Comment: good point, I am not working on the project atm, if you, @AnandSavjani are working on it and find an updated way of doing it with Maps, please edit the reponse; 10x

Comment: I have solved my problem with volley library which support all type of methods and content-type :)