# Jackson->Jackson + HttpPost = "Invalid UTF-8 middle byte", Setting Mime and Encoding

Tags: java, json, utf-8, jackson

I'm using the Apache HTTP Client libs and Jackson in my client.  When I post JSON to the server I get the error:

```
org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0x65
 at [Source: HttpInputOverHTTP@22a4ac95; line: 1, column: 81]
```

If I don't set any headers than I get `invalid media type`, which makes sense.

If I use curl and the same headers, the server accepts it, so I think the server is OK (and just a coincidence that it's also using Jackson)

These is the document; I've hard coded it as a Java literal using only 8 bit characters to avoid any other place for mangling to happen

```
// "Stra\u00DFe" = "Straße"
static String TINY_UTF8_DOC = "[{ \"id\" : \"2\", \"fields\" : { \"subject\" : [{ \"name\" : \"subject\", \"value\" : \"Stra\u00DFe\" }] } }]";
```

Here's the code I've been using, and comments with the various attempts:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost( url );

// Attempt A
// post.setEntity(  new StringEntity( content )  );

// Attempt B
// post.setEntity(  new StringEntity( content )  );
// post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

// Attempt C
// post.setEntity(  new StringEntity( content, ContentType.create("application/json") )  );

// Attempt D
// post.setEntity(  new StringEntity( content, ContentType.create("application/json; charset=UTF-8") )  );

// Attempt F
// post.setEntity(  new StringEntity( content, ContentType.create("application/json; charset=utf-8") )  );

// Attempt G
// StringEntity params = new StringEntity( content );
// params.setContentType("application/json; charset=UTF-8");
// post.setEntity(params);

// And then send to server
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute( post );
int code = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
// ...etc...
```

Other weird things I've noticed:

- For a while this behaved differently on Eclipse on the Mac vs. running a .jar on Linux; clearly that's a symptom of platform-specific encoding or decoding, but I don't know where.  Ironically that *broke* when I set Eclipse to treat code as UTF-8 (vs. ASCII)  I suspect this is an important clue, but not sure where it fits.
- I've seen times when instead of 2 bytes there's 4 bytes in the stream, though this might have been a different encoding problem when writing to disk, though I was specifically setting UTF-8 on file IO
- When I look at the string entity in the debugger, I see the bytes, but the 8-bit character is a negative number.  When you run through the Two's Compliment math, it is still the correct Unicode code point, so nominally OK, assuming httpclient isn't buggy.

Really out of ideas, and as I said, it works with curl, so I think the server is OK.

**Edit:**

curl works when posting to the server, but I can't share the server code.  It was pointed out that since curl isn't written in Java, and so perhaps it behaves differently, and therefore the server code could still be suspect.

So as a further test, the code below does **NOT** use the Apache httpclient library, and DOES work when posting to the server.  This proves that the server is fine and there's still something wrong with how I'm using the Apache library on the client side (or maybe it's buggy).

**Non-apache-httpclient code, which does work:**

```
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

class PostUtf8 {
    static String POST_URL = "http://...";

    // \u00DF = LATIN SMALL LETTER SHARP S, looks like letter B
    static String TINY_UTF8_DOC = "[{ \"id\" : \"2\", \"fields\" : { \"subject\" : [{ \"name\" : \"subject\", \"value\" : \"Stra\u00DFe\" }] } }]";

    public static void main( String [] args ) throws Exception {
        System.out.println( "Posting to " + POST_URL );
        URL url = new URL( POST_URL );
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8" );
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStream sout = conn.getOutputStream();
        OutputStreamWriter wout = new OutputStreamWriter(sout, "UTF-8" );
        wout.write( TINY_UTF8_DOC );
        wout.flush();
        int result = conn.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println( "Result = " + result );
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a problem here; here, `ß` is `\u00DF` as an escaped UTF-16 sequence but you read _byte_ 0x65; what is your source?

Comment: That UTF-8 error will only be produced if you are trying to read something as UTF-8 that is not UTF-8.  UTF-8 works by padding the first byte with 1's in the high-bit side to indicate how many bytes to read for the character.  The rest of the bytes have to start with '10', which sort of acts like check bits, else it knows there is a problem parsing.  In your case, you have a byte that has 1's in the left side, but not enough bytes after to satisfy the number specified.  Long story short, I would guess your client is not sending UTF-8 at all.  Reference:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

Comment: Can you try and double the backslash before `u00DF` so that the JSON reads "\u00DF"?

Comment: @CodeChimp thanks, I agree it's mis-encoded by the time it gets to the server, but the question is how/why?  Clearly I'm mis-using the client libs somehow, but all the examples I've seen seem to follow those patterns.

Comment: @fge to your first comment, backslash u and then 4 digits is the standard way to refer to a Uncode code point in Java, you typically wouldn't put \uDF (2 digits).  As I understand it, while in RAM, Java is using UTF-16 (or some variant) for characters, and only when you stream to/from files or other processes does it shift to UTF-8.

Comment: @fge to your second comment, putting 2 backslashes DOES work, which is cool, but it's a workaround.  The real data I'm getting doesn't come in like that, it's proper UTF-8 (on the way in), and stored as a proper 16 bit Java character once in memory. I used the backslash notation in my test just. So I can't just replace \ with \\, since there are no backslashes in the input. As an ugly workaround I guess I could look for any > 7-bit character and replace it with a backslash sequence, but I really shouldn't have to do that, the library should be doing that (if used properly and not not buggy).

Comment: Well, there's a problem in the way the JSON is read it seems. How is it read? From an `InputStream`?

Comment: @fge I'm pretty sure the server is reading the stream correctly, it works if I use curl.

Comment: Looking around I decided to try StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava and escapeJson from commons-lang3, but they also escape the quotation marks, etc, so not a good workaround.  This has gotta be a simple thing I'm doing wrong.

Comment: curl is not Java... Can you share the Java code used to read?

Comment: I can't really share that, but I believe it's using Jackson as well, a standard Java library. I'll ping the developers, and will post my workaround below.

Comment: This is a workaround to the problem. I'm not posting as an answer as I don't believe it's the "right" way to be doing it.  String escapeUnicode( String inBuff ) {
  StringBuffer outBuff = new StringBuffer();
  for ( int i = 0; i<inBuff.length(); i++ ) {
   char c = inBuff.charAt(i);
   int ic = c;
   if ( ic <= 127 ) {
    outBuff.append( c );
   }
   else {
    outBuff.append( "\\u" );
    outBuff.append( String.format("%04d", ic).toUpperCase() );
   }
  }
  return new String( outBuff );
 }

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352861/jackson-jsonparseexception-invalid-utf-8-middle-byte

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks like the problem is how the `ContentType` parameter for the HttpClient's `StringEntity` constructor is being created.

Using the `ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON` constant as a parameter (which corresponds to the "application/json; charset=utf-8" mime type) makes everything work.

Here is an example posting the JSON string to a public http service that echoes the request back to the client:

```
public class HttpClientEncoding {

    static String TINY_UTF8_DOC = "[{ \"id\" : \"2\", \"fields\" : { \"subject\" : " +
            "[{ \"name\" : \"subject\", \"value\" : \"Stra\u00DFe\" }] } }]";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://httpbin.org/post");
        StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(TINY_UTF8_DOC, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        //StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(TINY_UTF8_DOC, ContentType.create("application/json; charset=utf-8"));
        post.setEntity(entity);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);
        String result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        System.out.println(result);
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode node = mapper.readValue(result, JsonNode.class);
        System.out.println(node.get("json").get(0).get("fields").get("subject").get(0).get("value").asText());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "origin": "46.9.77.167",
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/post",
  "args": {},
  "data": "[{ \"id\" : \"2\", \"fields\" : { \"subject\" : [{ \"name\" : \"subject\", \"value\" : \"Stra\u00dfe\" }] } }]",
  "files": {},
  "form": {},
  "headers": {
    "Content-Length": "90",
    "User-Agent": "Apache-HttpClient/4.3.3 (java 1.5)",
    "Host": "httpbin.org",
    "Connection": "close",
    "X-Request-Id": "c02864cc-a1d6-434c-9cff-1f6187ceb080",
    "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
  },
  "json": [
    {
      "id": "2",
      "fields": {
        "subject": [
          {
            "value": "Stra\u00dfe",
            "name": "subject"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
Straße
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it. Looks like the constants-vs-strings is in newer versions, but examples I had found online were older. Thanks also for the link to the httpbin.org site, and example on reading the response as I'm new to this lib.

Comment: I tried to create the StringEntity with the `ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON` 2nd arg ... or to add a header to HttpPost object, like this `request.addHeader("Content-Type", ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON.toString());` . But i keep getting the same error "JsonMappingException: Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0xZZ" when my message contains 'é','è' or 'ô' for instance ... ZZ being an hexadecimal value which changed depending the values.

Comment: @Alex exactly the same situation here.. even I am getting them when using accented characters, hyphen and comma.. were you able to figure out what happened?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:(Specifying "UTF-8" to StringEntity)

```
        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(
                "/home/user/paylod.txt"));

        org.json.simple.JSONObject jsonObject = (org.json.simple.JSONObject) obj;

        StringEntity input = new StringEntity( jsonObject.toString(),"UTF-8");
        input.setContentType("application/json");
```