# jmeter Invalid UTF-8 middle byte

Tags: json, utf-8, jmeter

I'm using jMeter to shoot json through post requests to my test server.

the following request always fail:

```json
{
    "location": {
        "latitude": "37.390737",
        "longitude": "-121.973864"
    },
    "category": "Café & Bakeries"
}
```

the error message in the response data is:

```
Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0x20
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@6073ddf0; line: 6, column: 20]
```

The request is not sent to the server at all.
other requests (e.g. replacing the value in category with other valid category like "Delis") works perfectly.

I guess it's an encoding issue related to "Café" but I don't know how to resolve it.
any idea?
Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jackson JsonParseException: Invalid UTF-8 middle byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352861/jackson-jsonparseexception-invalid-utf-8-middle-byte)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in the HTTP request itself, it is possible to set "content encoding". I set there "utf-8" and it solved the problem

Comment: It worked for me, as simple as that, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably need an HTTP header to post that JSON:

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

Without this, it's likely that the string isn't UTF-8–encoded. JSON should be in UTF-8, so the hex bytes for `é` should be `0xc3 0xa9`.

Without that header, the byte sequence is probably `0xe9`, which is in ISO-8859-1 encoding. That would explain the error, as UTF-8 sequences starting `0xe_` are [3-byte sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Codepage_layout), so it sees `0xe9 0x20` (where `0x20` is the space after the `é`) and complains about an "invalid middle byte".

Source: [Posting a JSON request with JMeter](http://ppettitau.wordpress.com/2012/11/25/posting-a-json-request-with-jmeter/)

Comment: Thanks! I tried it but it didn't solve the problem...

here's how the header looks like:
Request Headers:
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 115
Host: 54.84.42.7:14080
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.2.6 (java 1.5)

Comment: I found the solution - in the HTTP request itself, it is possible to set "content encoding". I set there "utf-8" and it solved the problem.

cbuckley thanks for the lead!

Comment: @OfirKolar Ahi you should post an answer to your own question

Answer (score 0):

None of the above solutions worked for me in jmeter 5.2.1

What I tried?

1. Set the jmeter properties file: sampleresult.default.encoding=UTF-8  (Didn't work)
2. Set the header Content-Type=application/json;UTF-8 ( Didn't work)
3. Tried preProcessor sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).setValue(new String(utf8Bytes))  ( Didn't work)
4. Fortunately I noticed a field "Content encoding" ( As mentioned by  Ofir Kolar) which seem to worked finally

[image]