# Incorrect encoding in Jmeter http-requests to ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, jmeter

I am testing ElasticSearch with Jmeter tool and can't yet solve the case with incorrect http-requests encoding.

My Pipeline:

1. read csv file
2. make query to ElasticSearch

Test dataset contains strings in different languages.

For example,

QUERY_1

```
{
    "query":
    {
        "match":
        {
            "productTitle":
            {
                "query": "Arlo Ultra utendørs magnetisk ladekabel",
                "fuzziness": 0,
                "fuzzy_transpositions": "false",
                "operator": "and"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

RESPONSE_1

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"json_parse_exception",
"reason":"Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0xf8\n at [Source: (org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.ByteBufStreamInput); 
line: 8, column: 44]"}],"type":"json_parse_exception",
"reason":"Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0xf8\n at [Source: (org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.ByteBufStreamInput); 
line: 8, column: 44]"},"status":400}
```

The error occurs due to the 'ø' symbol (Norwegian)

If I run the same query in Kibana, the answer is correct.
So i think that the problem is with jmeter's encoding.

I am using for request Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8

Encoding in jmeter system.properties:

```
- file.encoding=UTF-8
- file.encoding.pkg=sun.io
- sun.io.unicode.encoding=UnicodeBig
- sun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8
```

And also

```
Jmeter ver.:        5.3
ElasticSearch ver.: 7.9
```

Will appreciate any advice !

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24629013/jmeter-invalid-utf-8-middle-byte

Comment: @user7294900, thanks.
I missed specifying the encoding in the HTTP Request Sampler setting.
It solved my case :)