# JsonParseException: Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0x2d

Tags: java, json, utf-8, jackson, avro

I have a JSON String from which I am making a `InputStream object` as shown below and then I am making a `GenericRecord` object as I am trying to serialize my JSON object to Avro schema.

```
InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(jsonString.getBytes());
DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(input);

Decoder decoder = DecoderFactory.get().jsonDecoder(schema, din);

DatumReader<GenericRecord> reader = new GenericDatumReader<GenericRecord>(schema);
// below line is throwing exception
GenericRecord datum = reader.read(null, decoder);
```

Below is the exception I am getting:

```
org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0x2d at [Source: java.io.DataInputStream@562aee31; line: 1, column: 74]
```

And here is the actual JSON string on which this exception is happening:

```
{"name":"car_test","attr_value":"2006|Renault|Megane II Coupé-Cabriolet|null|null|null|null|0|Wed Feb 03 10:00:59 GMT-07:00 2016|1|77|null|null|null|null","data_id":900}
```

I did some research and found out that I need to use `ByteArrayInputStream` with UTF-8 encodings as shown below:

```
InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(jsonString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.displayName()));
```

But my question is what is the reason of this exception? And why it is happening on my above JSON String? I am just trying to understand why this exception is happening on my above JSON String. And using `UTF-8` is the right fix for this?

What does this error means `Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0x2d`?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352861/jackson-jsonparseexception-invalid-utf-8-middle-byte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start with a Java Unicode String `jsonString`.

You then convert it into a byte stream using `String.getBytes()`. Since you didn't specify the byte encoding the platform default is used which is most likely ISO 8859-1.

Now you parse the JSON from the `(Data)InputStream`. Now Avro seems to use UTF-8 to decode the bytes. And when it encounters the `é` (0x2d) it fails since it is not a valid UTF byte sequence.

So in the end it is a mismatch between the actual encoding (ISO 8859-1) and the expected encoding (UTF-8).

You can solve this like you did, or just avoid to go from string to bytes:

```
Decoder decoder = DecoderFactory.get().jsonDecoder(schema, jsonString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using low-level Avro decoder functionality, you might be interested in a more convenient approach with Jackson Avro module:

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-avro/issues

in which you can provide Avro Schema, but still work with POJOs.
You can also use regular JSON Jackson databinding (different `ObjectMapper`) for JSON part, and read JSON into POJO, write POJO as Avro (or other combinations).