# Process input json with illegal encoding

Tags: java, json, encoding, character-encoding, jackson

My java app has consumer that gets on input JSON files from server and then I tries convert it using Jackson. But ObjectMapper throws an exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0x2f
```

As far as I understand it's is due to incorrect encoding.
Can I somehow recognize the encoding and process the server response?

Comment: take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352861/json-invalid-utf-8-middle-byte

Comment: The server may send a `Content-Type` header specifying the encoding along with the data. If no encoding is specified, UTF-8 is the default for `application/json`. In this case fix the server to send correctly encoded Json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was needed to recognize the encoding and correctly process the data.
For that I used UniversalDetector from `org.mozilla.universalchardet.UniversalDetector`

```
private static final UniversalDetector DETECTOR = new UniversalDetector(null);

private static String getEncode(byte[] data) throws IOException {
    DETECTOR.reset();

    byte[] buf = new byte[data.length];
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);

    int read;
    while ((read = is.read(buf)) > 0 && !DETECTOR.isDone()) {
        DETECTOR.handleData(buf, 0, read);
    }
    is.close();

    DETECTOR.dataEnd();
    return DETECTOR.getDetectedCharset();
}
```

And then I read it with correct encode:

```
private static String readWithEncode(byte[] data, String encoding) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(data), encoding));
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    String s;
    while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
        result.append(s);
    }
    br.close();
    return result.toString();
}
```