# Can not send request with body contain some special character like ß

Tags: spring-boot, character-encoding

When I send POST request that body request contains some special character like ß, actually it is a character in German like "Zentrale Bußgeldstelle". And bellow is the information of request I sent by using curl run on Gitbash:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8080/user/v1/register' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "username": "ßtest",
    "password": "P@ssword"
}'
```

And I got the bad request status as below:

```
{
   "timestamp":"2020-06-27T05:22:50.676+0000",
   "status":400,
   "error":"Bad Request",
   "message":"JSON parse error: Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0x74\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); 
    line: 1, column: 18]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0x74\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 18]\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 15] (through reference chain: com.example.springlogin.dto.UserDto[\"username\"])",
   "path":"/user/v1/register"
}
```

I faced that it related to ß character. But the issue not occur when I send that request using postman.I used Springboot to implement that api.

So anyone can help to solve my above issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: try adding charset=utf-8 to Content-Type

Comment: Thanks for quick response, already add but still got the same isssue

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352861/json-invalid-utf-8-middle-byte

Comment: Thanks all for some responses. after investigating and debug. The root cause is actually from consumer side with using wrong encoding ( not utf-8). The final solution is just using utf-8 from consumer side.

Comment: Please post that as and answer and accept it so that other can be benefited from that as well!